# How can Add the text filed like custom price in sales->orders and store in database table Magento 1.9?

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I want add the text field like custom product description (refer screenshot) and Store the value in the sales order table 
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far, where is the relevant code?

Comment: i dont have idea i just edit grid,phtml for add the input field

Answer (score 0):

1. Add new catalog_product attribute and create local Module (yournamespace_customattribute)
2. Add new attribute to order item entity via setup script

   ```
   $install = new Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Setup('core_setup');

   $options = array(
       'type'     => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR,
       'visible'  => true,
       'required' => false
   );

   $install->addAttribute('quote_item', 'custom_product_description', $options); 
   $install->addAttribute('order_item', 'custom_product_description', $options); 

   $install->endSetup();
   ```
3. Add attribute in config.xml

```html
    <sales>
        <quote>
            <item>
                <product_attributes>
                    <custom_product_description />
                </product_attributes>
            </item>
        </quote>
    </sales>
```

4. Add observer method in config.xml

```html
    <sales_quote_item_set_product>
        <observers>
            <yournamespace_customattribute>
                <class>yournamespace_customattribute/observer</class>
                <method>salesQuoteItemSetCustomAttribute</method>
            </yournamespace_customattribute>
        </observers>
    </sales_quote_item_set_product>
```

5. Add method salesQuoteItemSetCustomAttribute into Observer.php

```js
    public function salesQuoteItemSetCustomAttribute($observer)
    {
        $quoteItem = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        $product = $observer->getProduct();
        $quoteItem->setCustomProductDescription($product->getCustomProductDescription());
    }
```

6. Finally to pass values into sales flat table add this to global in config.xml

```html
    <fieldsets>
        <sales_convert_quote_item>
            <custom_product_description>
                <to_order_item>*</to_order_item>
            </custom_product_description>
        </sales_convert_quote_item>
        <sales_convert_order_item>
            <custom_product_description>
                <to_quote_item>*</to_quote_item>
            </custom_product_description>
        </sales_convert_order_item>
    </fieldsets>
```

Comment: hi sam thank you for your answer  but i need to edit custom product description field, if you add the product attribute you cant edit.
finaly i want the  custom product description field editable

Comment: i guess you missed the complexity of extending order item fields. custom attribute is needed to add database structure. Observer method will do the saving process.